# elasticsearch ngram analyzer/tokenizer not working?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

it seems that the ngram tokenizer isn't working or perhaps my understanding/use of it isn't correct.

my tokenizer is doing a mingram of 3 and maxgram of 5. i'm looking for the term 'madonna' which is definitely in my documents under artists.name. i can find the term with other techniques (using simple analyzer and related), but not using ngram.

what i'm trying to accomplish by using the ngram is to find names and accounting for misspellings.

please see a shortened version of my mappings, my settings, and my query, and if you have any ideas, please let me know - it's driving me nuts!

settings...

```
{
   "myindex": {
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "analysis": {
               "analyzer": {                  
                  "ngramAnalyzer": {
                     "type": "custom",
                     "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                     ],
                     "tokenizer": "nGramTokenizer"
                  }  
               },
               "tokenizer": {
                  "nGramTokenizer": {
                     "type": "nGram",
                     "min_gram": "3",
                     "max_gram": "5"
                  }
               }
            },
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "version": {
               "created": "1020199"
            },
            "uuid": "60ggSr6TREaDTItkaNUagg"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

mappings ...

```
{
   "myindex": {
      "mappings": {
         "mytype": {
            "properties": { 
               "artists.name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "simple",
                  "fields": {
                     "ngram": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "ngramAnalyzer"
                     },
                     "raw": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

query ...

```
{"query": {"match": {"artists.name.ngram": "madonna"}}}
```

document ...

```
{
   "_index": "myindex",
   "_type": "mytype",
   "_id": "602537592951",
   "_version": 1,
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
      "artists": [
         {
            "name": "Madonna",
            "id": "P    64565"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**EDIT**
incidentally, this query works (without ngram):

```
{"query": {"match": {"artists.name": "madonna"}}}
```

this obviously has something to do with the nested object here. i'm apparently not applying the ngram to the nested object properly.

ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok - i figured it out. i really hope this helps someone b/c it drove me crazy.

here's what my mapping turned out to look like:

```
{
   "myindex": {
      "mappings": {
         "mytype": {
            "properties": {               
               "artists": {
                  "properties": {
                     "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "ngramAnalyzer",
                        "fields": {
                           "raw": {
                              "type": "string",
                              "index": "not_analyzed"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here's how i did it using Nest syntax...

first i had a sub type (class) called Person which has a Name and Id which looks like this (POCO)...

```
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(Analyzer = "fullTerm", Index = FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

and then my mapping went something like this ...

```
.AddMapping<MyIndex>(m => m
.MapFromAttributes()
.Properties(props =>
{
    props           
        .Object<Person>(x => x.Name("artists")
        .Properties(pp => pp
            .MultiField(
                mf => mf
                .Name(s => s.Name)
                .Fields(f => f
                    .String(s => s.Name(o => o.Name).Analyzer("ngramAnalyzer"))
                    .String(s => s.Name(o => o.Name.Suffix("raw")).Index(FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed))
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Note: the Object here which indicates it's another object beneath my type 'artists'.

**Thanks, me!!!**

> edit:
>   curl mappings might be something like this...

```
curl-XPOST"http://localhost:9200/yourindex/_mappings"-H'Content-Type:application/json'-d'{"myindex":{"mappings":{"mytype":{"properties":{"artists":{"properties":{"id":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string","analyzer":"ngramAnalyzer","fields":{"raw":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}}}}}}}}}}'
```

Comment: Can you tell me how the final mapping and the query shoud be in curl syntax